# Pygame can't create if statment for restart screen?

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to create a code for creating restart section. I created a variable and set to True.
And said if that variable true do everything in game if not press space and restart the game.
Now space bar now working and games not restarting. What is wrong? And every time I ask something on this site I get bullied over here so take it easy Im pretty new.

Code:

```
    if game_active:

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and player_rect.bottom >= 300:
                player_gravity = -20
    else:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_SPACE:
            game_active = True
```

Code for setting false to game_active when player and enemy collapse:

```
        if snail_rect.colliderect(player_rect):
            game_active = False

        else:
            screen.fill('Yellow')
```

Comment: can u paste a reproducible code

Comment: I would do but ı couldn't fınd how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
```

You missed the event.key part.